# How can I capitalize a string showed by Thymeleaf into a page?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, thymeleaf, capitalization

I am working on a Spring MVC application that uses Thymeleaf as template engine and I am trying to capitalize some string showed into my page. On my page I have something like this:

```
<li class="com__nav-item" th:each="menuItem : ${#authentication.principal.listaFunzioniUtente}">
    <a href="" class="com__nav-link centered">
        <span class="blue-line animate scaleIn delay-3" style="font-size: 1.4em; text-align: center;" th:text="${#strings.capitalize(menuItem.desFnz)}"></span>
        <span class="white-circle animate scaleIn delay-5"></span>
    </a>
</li>
```

As you can see in the previous code, in the first `<span>` tag, I show a string inside the `desFnz` property of the `menuItem` object.

It works fine, my problem is that I want capitalize all the characters, so I tried to do:

```
th:text="${#strings.capitalize(menuItem.desFnz)}"
```

using the `#strings.capitalize()` but it can't work, in fact in my page I still obtain the text but not capitalized. Why? What am I missing? How can I fix this issue?

Comment: Which Thymeleaf version do you use ?

Comment: @Zakaria I am using the 2.1.4.RELEASE of ThymeLeaf

Answer (score 33, accepted):

`#strings.capitalize(menuItem.desFnz)` will only capitalize the 1st character, where as `#strings.toUpperCase(menuItem.desFnz)` will convert the entire string to uppercase. [Here is the documentation for the Strings class.](http://www.thymeleaf.org/apidocs/thymeleaf/2.0.5/org/thymeleaf/expression/Strings.html)

Answer (score 4):

you can do it by

`$string.toLowerCase()` or `$string.toUpperCase()`

Answer (score 0):

Just adding to Pradeep Pati's point.
In case you are using it in the spring boot project where some of your values are coming from `messages.properties`

like In messages.properties file, You have something like:

`email.dailyAlert.greeting.newTemplate = Dear {0},`

Then to substitute the value in place of {0} (in the Title case), you need to write like the below line.

```
<p th:text="#{email.dailyAlert.greeting.newTemplate(${#strings.capitalize(orgSlug)})}"></p>
```

The final output will be:

Dear Organisation,

---