# Thymeleaf: populating checkboxes from an Array

Tags: spring-mvc, enums, thymeleaf

I have a Spring MVC application using Thymeleaf for templating. I am using enums to  generate checkboxes dynamically. So if my enum file has 3 values it will generate 3 checkboxes:

My enum file:

```
public enum Foods {

    PIZZA("Pizza"),
    PASTA("Pasta"),
    MAC_CHEESE("Mac and Cheese"),
    ICE_CREAM("Ice Cream"),
    BURGER("Burger"),

    private String type;

    Foods(String type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

    public String getType() {
        return this.type;
    }

}
```

This is my checkbox generation:

```
<label for="decision">What is your favorite food?</label>
<div id="decision" class="row" style="margin-top:1%;">
    <div class="col-md-4" th:each="option : ${T(in.app.model.enums.Foods).values()}">
        <div class="checkbox checkbox-custom checkbox-circle">
            <input name="decision" type="checkbox" th:id="${option.toString()}" th:value="${option}" />
            <label th:for="${option.toString()}" th:text="${option.type}"></label>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This code will generate 5 checkboxes for each of the food type. All works till here. The issue I am facing is how to set the checked attribute when reading a saved record.

I am getting back an object via the model view controller. The object has a food property with its value as the array of the chosen food types.

```
user = {
   .
   .
   food : ["PIZZA", "BURGER", "PASTA"],
   .
   .
}
```

Now I want to loop through this array and if the value match then set the checkbox.

I am trying to do something like this:

```
<label for="decision">What is your favorite food?</label>
<div id="decision" class="row" style="margin-top:1%;">
    <div class="col-md-4" th:each="option : ${T(in.app.model.enums.Foods).values()}">
        <div class="checkbox checkbox-custom checkbox-circle">
            <input 
                name="decision" 
                type="checkbox" 
                th:id="${option.toString()}" 
                th:value="${option}" 
                th:each="food : ${user.food}"
                th:attr="checked = ${food} == ${option} ? 'checked'"
            />
            <label th:for="${option.toString()}" th:text="${option.type}"></label>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I know its wrong (since its not working) but I am unable to figure out how to loop over two arrays to show the checkboxes and to check them.

Comment: Could you post what is being output by the application, or any errors associate with it from thymeleaf?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try using [th:checked](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/2.1/usingthymeleaf.html#fixed-value-boolean-attributes) instead of th:attr if you can, so:

```
th:checked="${food == option.type}"
```

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29826576/thymeleaf-how-to-add-checked-attribute-to-input-conditionally) post might also be helpful when looking into that. If you can't use th:checked, switching to the below statement should also work.

```
th:attr="checked=${food == option.type} ? 'checked'"
```

It also seems like you may run into some issues with checking this data due to case sensitivity while comparing, in which case [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36019903/9322871) post might be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

The safe option is to go with

```
th:attr
```

and do compare like @Artichoke

```
th:attr="checked=${food == option.type} ? 'checked'"
```

The problem with `"th:checked"` is, its simply do not go well when you need to post the data unless you change the value. You see its value as null if you do not switch it.